# Invalid SchemaName: None on EPPlus (Solved)

Tags: c#, epplus

I am doing some changes to a pre-filled excel file just with the sheets and the headers of these sheets. When i try to return it as a MemoryStream, the code raises a **"System.ArgumentException: Invalid schemaname: none"**.
I have followed the EPPlus tutorials and conventions, still this exception is thrown.
Does someone came across with something similar to this?
PS: Commented code was just an example

Code for example:

```
public static MemoryStream GetMemoryStreamExcel(DataSet dsModel, string modelFileLocation)
        {
            MemoryStream ms;
            FileInfo existingModelFile = new FileInfo(modelFileLocation);
            byte[] result = new byte[0];

            using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(existingModelFile))
            {
                foreach (DataTable table in dsModel.Tables)
                {   
                    var sheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets[table.TableName];
                    
                    sheet.Cells["A2"].LoadFromDataTable(table, PrintHeaders: false);
                    //sheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Test Of File";
                }
                ms = new MemoryStream(p.GetAsByteArray());
            };
            return ms;
        }
```

Comment: Solved. For some odd reason, after saving the excel file on Microsoft Excel instead of Libre office, replace it on the folder and pass the **p.GetAsByteArray()** to the **result** byte array before creating the new MemoryStream, solved the problem.